# Help with Routing..RouteEventArgs cannot be serialized

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, arcgis-rest-api, geocortex

I created a routing service in ArcGIS Server that allows the Service Area task.  I've hit the REST service for this routing service and passed in a single facility XY and it works perfectly fine.  The trouble I'm having is in the Silverlight Geocortex application.  I'm using the RouteTask activity which simply ask for the Routing service URL (I provided: `http://server/ArcGIS/rest/services/Water/WaterRoadNWwithService/NAServer/ServiceArea/solveServiceArea`), route parameters (I provided multiple variables like facilities, out spatialreference, etc), and lastly a result (which should be of RouteEventArgs).  Whenever I run the task, I keep getting the below error and I'm not sure why or what to do next...

[image]

Type ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.RouteEventArgs cannot be serialized.  Consider making it with the DataContractAttribute attribute and marking all of its members you want serialized with DataMemberAttribute attribute

Comment: Any ideas?  I'm confident if I can get passed this error I'll be able to produce the service area polygon.  Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geocortex Workflow activities have two places where they run: on the server and on the client.

When an activity must transfer from the server to the client or vice versa, all in-scope variables are serialized so they can be transferred.  If any objects exist that can't be serialized, you will see this error, usually when moving from the server to the client.  So, your geoprocessing task requires a `RouteEventArgs` to work.  If you have a client activity (like an Alert!) after the Geoprocessing Task activity, then this Workflow will try to bring the RouteEventArgs along for the ride!

To avoid this behaviour, use a Sequence to perform all your server-side activities, and set the scope of the non-serializable variables within that Sequence.

It can be helpful to rename your sequence to keep track of variable scope.

[image]

Essentials 3.15 includes a new **Server Scope** activity that will produce an error if it detects any non-serializable variables within.  It's handy for ensuring that your server-side activities are safely contained on the server.